# Why do I get ImportError: No module named 'PIL'?

Tags: python, image, import

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

 ........
MY_IMAGE = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('1')
```

Should I first specify directory? I also tried:

```
  import Image
  img = Image.open("/directory/image.jpg")
  img.load()
```

It does not help, I still get ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: have you already install PIL correctly? `sudo pip install -v PIL`

Comment: I have not yet. drats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssQAFIQ4oBU
You need to install PIL first